# What is the job title of a professor who teaches Classics?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english, british-english, nouns

- Someone who is qualified to teach history is called *a History teacher*
- Someone who teaches music is a *Music teacher*
- … who teaches English to native speakers is an *English teacher*
- … teaches English as a second language can be referred to as an *English language teacher*

But what about [***classics***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classics)? A person who teaches the civilisation, history and art of the ancient Greeks and Romans is a…?

It seems that the title ***[Classical Studies teacher](http://www.open.ac.uk/blogs/classicalstudies/?p=507)*** is still in use in the UK but less so in the USA.

> Paul Found, Classical Studies teacher and former OU (Open University) student

- What do you call someone who teaches Classics in the US?  Would “Classical Studies teacher” be understood there?
- Can I say that someone is a  **Classicist professor** at XYZ university? It sounds awkward to my ears, so is there a more common expression in the US and/or in the UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One who teaches in the Classics Department is a classicist aka Classics scholar.

**classicist professor** is not idiomatic.

**Classics professor** or **Classics teacher** is what the person is called informally in the US.

The "job title" may vary according to where the person is on the "tenure track":

Assistant Professor of Classics.

Associate Professor of Classics.

Professor of Classics.

If the person is not on the tenure track:

Adjunct Professor of Classics.

Adjunct Instructor of Classics.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say a "classicist professor" but simply a [**classicist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classicist):

> an advocate or follower of classicism
>
> a classical scholar
>
> an expert in ancient Greek and Roman language, literature, art, architecture, or culture
>
> someone who prefers a traditional and usually graceful and simple style in art, literature, music, architecture, etc. : a person who favors classicism

Answer (score 1):

Classics teacher (in school). Professor of Classics at university (Professor has a different meaning in the US compared with the UK). A particular person may have a specific job title:

> Professor Mary Beard. Professor of Classics. (Cambridge); Alvan Talcott Professor of Classics (Yale)
>
> Professor Simon Goldhill. Professor of Greek Literature and Culture; Fellow and Director of Studies in Classics at King's College;

However the basis of most classical education is the study of the Latin Language, so "Latin teacher" is how such a person would probably be known at school. Even if they also teach classical civiliation or Greek, Latin is the core part of their job.

Comment: Thank you for taking up the time to post an answer, it was a difficult choice to make but TRomano's answer, I felt, had the edge for what I really needed to know.